# hovering over an element triggers an effect on another element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

We were given an assignment on Events and I’m kind of having a hard time figuring out. I actually have tried making my own code but I had it checked here and it apparently had a lot of errors and although they did explain what were the errors, I couldn’t really understand it and now I’m kind of embarrassed to show what I already tried so I’m just going to ask you guys to help me.

I want it that if I hover over a class “one”, div class “sqt” will have a 10px dotted green border, a background of lightgreen and a font color of #eca261 such as the photo below.

```html
<a class="one" href=#>First Link</a>
<a class="two" href=#>Second Link</a>
<br><br>
<div class="sqo">Div 1 here</div>
<br>
<div class="sqt">Div 2 here</div>
```

[image: image.jpg]

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, along with a description of what isn't working. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example If you are completely stuck then look carefully at the way elements can 'influence' their subsequent siblings See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. CSS is explained in the code.

Specific item to study: [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

```css
/*
  When class one is hovered, find the sibling with class sqt
*/
.one:hover ~ .sqt {
  font: #eca261;
  background: lightgreen;
  border: 10px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<a class="one" href=#>First Link</a>
<a class="two" href=#>Second Link</a>
<br><br>
<div class="sqo">Div 1 here</div>
<br>
<div class="sqt">Div 2 here</div>
```